# how to plot data which contains imaginary number

Tags: plotting

I have a data which contains real values in x and imaginary values in y, I wanted to plot this set of data but I could not able to plot. How to carry out this? I am getting some wired plot, with which I cannot able to any conclusions.

```
data={{6.28319, 0. - 198342. I}, {12.5664, 0. - 97729.6 I}, {18.8496, 
  0. - 63550.7 I}, {25.1327, 0. - 45978.9 I}, {31.4159, 
  0. - 35048.9 I}, {37.6991, 0. - 27438.5 I}, {43.9823, 
  0. - 21723.7 I}, {50.2655, 0. - 17192. I}, {56.5487, 
  0. - 13447.7 I}, {62.8319, 0. - 10253.2 I}, {69.115, 
  0. - 7456.79 I}, {75.3982, 0. - 4957.45 I}, {81.6814, 
  0. - 2684.93 I}, {87.9646, 0. - 588.956 I}, {94.2478, 
  0. - 1367.53 I}, {100.531, 0. - 3212.47 I}, {106.814, 
  0. - 4967.37 I}, {113.097, 0. - 6649.18 I}, {119.381, 
  0. - 8271.36 I}, {125.664, 0. - 9844.87 I}, {131.947, 
  0. - 11378.8 I}, {138.23, 0. - 12880.6 I}, {144.513, 
  0. - 14356.8 I}, {150.796, 0. - 15812.9 I}, {157.08, 
  0. - 17253.7 I}, {163.363, 0. - 18683.6 I}, {169.646, 
  0. - 20106.4 I}, {175.929, 0. - 21525.6 I}, {182.212, 
  0. - 22944.6 I}, {188.496, 0. - 24366.5 I}, {194.779, 
  0. - 25794.1 I}, {201.062, 0. - 27230.6 I}, {207.345, 
  0. - 28678.8 I}, {213.628, 0. - 30141.5 I}, {219.911, 
  0. - 31622.1 I}, {226.195, 0. - 33123.3 I}, {232.478, 
  0. - 34648.9 I}, {238.761, 0. - 36202.1 I}, {245.044, 
  0. - 37787.5 I}, {251.327, 0. - 39409.2 I}, {257.611, 
  0. - 41072.8 I}, {263.894, 0. - 42784. I}, {270.177, 
  0. - 44550.2 I}, {276.46, 0. - 46380.4 I}, {282.743, 
  0. - 48285.6 I}, {289.027, 0. - 50280.5 I}, {295.31, 
  0. - 52384.7 I}, {301.593, 0. - 54625.7 I}, {307.876, 
  0. - 57043.8 I}, {314.159, 0. - 59702.4 I}, {320.442, 
  0. - 62708.3 I}, {326.726, 0. - 66259.5 I}, {333.009, 
  0. - 70775.6 I}, {339.292, 0. - 77341.1 I}, {345.575, 
  0. - 89935.4 I}, {351.858, 0. - 144924. I}, {358.142, 
  0. - 6836. I}, {364.425, 0. - 45792.9 I}, {370.708, 
  0. - 58601.2 I}, {376.991, 0. - 65744.9 I}, {383.274, 
  0. - 71094.9 I}, {389.557, 0. - 75723.8 I}, {395.841, 
  0. - 80058. I}, {402.124, 0. - 84308.7 I}, {408.407, 
  0. - 88601.8 I}, {414.69, 0. - 93024.6 I}, {420.973, 
  0. - 97647.3 I}, {427.257, 0. - 102534. I}, {433.54, 
  0. - 107748. I}, {439.823, 0. - 113359. I}, {446.106, 
  0. - 119443. I}, {452.389, 0. - 126094. I}, {458.673, 
  0. - 133420. I}, {464.956, 0. - 141558. I}, {471.239, 
  0. - 150676. I}, {477.522, 0. - 160994. I}, {483.805, 
  0. - 172796. I}, {490.088, 0. - 186461. I}, {496.372, 
  0. - 202511. I}, {502.655, 0. - 221672. I}, {508.938, 
  0. - 245002. I}, {515.221, 0. - 274097. I}, {521.504, 
  0. - 311482. I}, {527.788, 0. - 361408. I}, {534.071, 
  0. - 431627. I}, {540.354, 0. - 537933. I}, {546.637, 
  0. - 718244. I}, {552.92, 0. - 1.09223*10^6 I}, {559.203, 
  0. - 2.33918*10^6 I}, {565.487, 0. - 1.36441*10^7 I}, {571.77, 
  0. - 1.69973*10^6 I}, {578.053, 0. - 893437. I}, {584.336, 
  0. - 599544. I}, {590.619, 0. - 447162. I}, {596.903, 
  0. - 353773. I}, {603.186, 0. - 290575. I}, {609.469, 
  0. - 244891. I}, {615.752, 0. - 210271. I}, {622.035, 
  0. - 183083. I}, {628.319, 0. - 161131. I}, {634.602, 
  0. - 143004. I}, {640.885, 0. - 127758. I}, {647.168, 
  0. - 114734. I}, {653.451, 0. - 103462. I}, {659.734, 
  0. - 93593.8 I}, {666.018, 0. - 84868.6 I}, {672.301, 
  0. - 77085.7 I}, {678.584, 0. - 70089. I}, {684.867, 
  0. - 63755.6 I}, {691.15, 0. - 57986.1 I}, {697.434, 
  0. - 52700.3 I}, {703.717, 0. - 47832.3 I}, {710., 
  0. - 43327.5 I}, {716.283, 0. - 39140.8 I}, {722.566, 
  0. - 35233.6 I}, {728.849, 0. - 31573.8 I}, {735.133, 
  0. - 28133.6 I}, {741.416, 0. - 24889.3 I}, {747.699, 
  0. - 21820.4 I}, {753.982, 0. - 18909.2 I}, {760.265, 
  0. - 16140.1 I}, {766.549, 0. - 13499.5 I}, {772.832, 
  0. - 10975.5 I}, {779.115, 0. - 8557.52 I}, {785.398, 
  0. - 6236.11 I}, {791.681, 0. - 4002.95 I}, {797.965, 
  0. - 1850.57 I}, {804.248, 0. - 227.748 I}, {810.531, 
  0. - 2238.03 I}, {816.814, 0. - 4185.72 I}, {823.097, 
  0. - 6075.74 I}, {829.38, 0. - 7912.58 I}, {835.664, 
  0. - 9700.34 I}, {841.947, 0. - 11442.6 I}, {848.23, 
  0. - 13143. I}, {854.513, 0. - 14804.4 I}, {860.796, 
  0. - 16429.9 I}, {867.08, 0. - 18022. I}, {873.363, 
  0. - 19583.3 I}, {879.646, 0. - 21115.8 I}, {885.929, 
  0. - 22621.9 I}, {892.212, 0. - 24103.4 I}, {898.495, 
  0. - 25562.2 I}, {904.779, 0. - 26999.9 I}, {911.062, 
  0. - 28418.3 I}, {917.345, 0. - 29818.8 I}, {923.628, 
  0. - 31202.8 I}, {929.911, 0. - 32571.6 I}, {936.195, 
  0. - 33926.6 I}, {942.478, 0. - 35269. I}, {948.761, 
  0. - 36599.9 I}, {955.044, 0. - 37920.4 I}, {961.327, 
  0. - 39231.5 I}, {967.611, 0. - 40534.4 I}, {973.894, 
  0. - 41830. I}, {980.177, 0. - 43119.1 I}, {986.46, 
  0. - 44402.8 I}, {992.743, 0. - 45681.9 I}, {999.026, 
  0. - 46957.3 I}, {1005.31, 0. - 48229.9 I}, {1011.59, 
  0. - 49500.5 I}, {1017.88, 0. - 50769.9 I}, {1024.16, 
  0. - 52038.9 I}, {1030.44, 0. - 53308.3 I}, {1036.73, 
  0. - 54579.4 I}, {1043.01, 0. - 55852.2 I}, {1049.29, 
  0. - 57127.8 I}, {1055.58, 0. - 58407.4 I}, {1061.86, 
  0. - 59691.8 I}, {1068.14, 0. - 60981.5 I}, {1074.42, 
  0. - 62277.5 I}, {1080.71, 0. - 63580.5 I}, {1086.99, 
  0. - 64892.2 I}, {1093.27, 0. - 66212.8 I}, {1099.56, 
  0. - 67543.8 I}, {1105.84, 0. - 68885.6 I}, {1112.12, 
  0. - 70240.2 I}, {1118.41, 0. - 71607.6 I}, {1124.69, 
  0. - 72990.5 I}, {1130.97, 0. - 74388.9 I}, {1137.26, 
  0. - 75805.1 I}, {1143.54, 0. - 77239.8 I}, {1149.82, 
  0. - 78695.1 I}, {1156.11, 0. - 80172.4 I}, {1162.39, 
  0. - 81674. I}, {1168.67, 0. - 83201.7 I}, {1174.96, 
  0. - 84757.9 I}, {1181.24, 0. - 86344. I}, {1187.52, 
  0. - 87963.9 I}, {1193.81, 0. - 89620.1 I}, {1200.09, 
  0. - 91315.8 I}, {1206.37, 0. - 93054.8 I}, {1212.65, 
  0. - 94841.1 I}, {1218.94, 0. - 96679.4 I}, {1225.22, 
  0. - 98575. I}, {1231.5, 0. - 100534. I}, {1237.79, 
  0. - 102563. I}, {1244.07, 0. - 104670. I}, {1250.35, 
  0. - 106864. I}, {1256.64, 0. - 109156. I}}  
ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ data, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Try 3d plot to this end.

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: Think of {#[[1]], Re[#[[2]]], Im[#[[2]]]} & /@ data.

Comment: Search Argand diagram on SE

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
ListPointPlot3D[{#[[1]], Re[#[[2]]], Im[#[[2]]]} & /@ data]
```

[image]

Comment: I think he wants so plot it in the complex plane in the usual representation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're trying to have the x-axis be the real numbers and the y-axis the imaginary numbers.

If that's what you're trying to do, you're very close!

Try:

```
ListPlot[{Re[#[[1]]], Im[#[[2]]]} & /@ data, PlotRange -> All]
```

This will extract the real part of the x component and the imaginary part of the y component. You end up with:

[image: Plot of complex points.]

Comment: Perhaps `{First@#, Im@Last@#} &` is easier to read ...

Comment: @Alan That's a good point. I have the MMA double square bracket hot-keyed so I usually end up using that instead. I agree that it looks cluttered having all those single square brackets.